# Google Maps + CustomPaint Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

When placing a CustomPaint widget on top of Google maps widget, the map is no longer receiving touch events (scrolling, pan, tap, ..etc).

Is it possible to put CustomPaint widget above map while keeping map interactive? 
Here is a sample code explaining the case:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() =>
    runApp(
        MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Google Maps Demo',
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Scaffold(
              body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
                    zoom: 14.4746,
                  ),
                ),
                CustomPaint(
                  painter: ShapesPainter(),
                  child: Container(height: 500),
                )
              ],)

            ),
          ),
        )
    );

class ShapesPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Color(0xFF3f6cbf);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0, 0), 300, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: what does `ShapesPainter#hitTest` return?

Comment: I didn't override hitTest. Question is now updated with complete code.

Comment: so do that and see what happens if you return non `null` value

Comment: Overriding hitTest and returning false solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: good, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `CustomPainter` widget with `IgnorePointer`
it will ignore any click or other gestures read more

**Final code**

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
        zoom: 14.4746,
      ),
    ),
    IgnorePointer(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: ShapesPainter(),
        child: Container(height: 500),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```